# classification_report parameters for decision trees (precision, recall, f1-score, support) coming as 1.0

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a dataframe with 21 columns and 260616 rows. I wanted to build a decision tree classification model for a status variable. I have cleaned the data and made all the variables into proper datatypes. Below is the summary of all the columns in the data -

**Data columns (total 21 columns):**

*Brand                         (260616 non-null object)*

*Order_Line_Id                 (260616 non-null object)*

*Order_Type                    (260616 non-null object)*

*OLSC_FC_Name                  (260616 non-null object)*

*FC_Id                         (260616 non-null object)*

*OLSC_Day_Of_the_week          (260616 non-null object)*

*OLSAC_Reason                  (260616 non-null object)*

*Inv_Qty                       (260616 non-null int64)*

*Gender                        (260616 non-null object)*

*Category                      (260616 non-null object)*

*Subcategory                   (260616 non-null object)*

*SubBrand                      (260616 non-null object)*

*Season                        (260616 non-null object)*

*FC_Type                       (260616 non-null object)*

*Order_Month                   (260616 non-null int64)*

*OLSC_Month                    (260616 non-null int64)*

*OLSC_Hour                     (260616 non-null int64)*

*Assignment_Hour               (260616 non-null int64)*

*Assignment_Day_of_the_week    (260616 non-null object)*

*A2MPF                         (260616 non-null float64)*

*OLSC_Status                   (260616 non-null object)*

- OLSC_FC_Name has 540 unique values and around 26 Brand values.
- OLSC_Status has two values, which is also my categorical dependent variable.
- [Here is the image of OLSC Status values mix in test and training set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gGIw.png)

I opted for the decision tree model as a start to see if I can see any meaningful result to take it up a notch.

I encoded all the categorical variables using Label Encoder, made OLSC_Status datatype as 'category', split the test train with 70:30 ratio, and wrote the algorithm code with DecisionTreeClassifier.

But the scores for precision, recall, f1-score, support were all 1.0, which is weird.

The tree came out to have only two levels.

And it is completely wrong. I need help in understanding what am i doing wrong? Also, which algorithm is the most optimal one for this kind of a problem.

Below is the code for Decision Tree algo that I have used.

```
# Splitting the data into train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                                    test_size=0.30, 
                                                    random_state = 99)
X_train.head()

y_train.value_counts()

y_test.value_counts()

# Importing decision tree classifier from sklearn library
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

# Fitting the decision tree with default hyperparameters, apart from
# max_depth which is 5 so that we can plot and read the tree.
dt_default = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=10)
dt_default.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Let's check the evaluation metrics of our default model

# Importing classification report and confusion matrix from sklearn metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score

# Making predictions
y_pred_default = dt_default.predict(X_test)

# Printing classification report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred_default))

# Printing confusion matrix and accuracy
print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred_default))
print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred_default))

# Importing required packages for visualization
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus, graphviz

# Putting features
features = list(df_ca.columns[1:])
features

# plotting tree with max_depth=10
dot_data = StringIO()  
export_graphviz(dt_default, out_file=dot_data,
                feature_names=features, filled=True,rounded=True)

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

[Here is the image with the final decision tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnlkM.png)

Comment: I transformed the categorical variables into numerical labels using Label Encoder. ```le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()                                                 
 df_categorical.apply(le.fit_transform)
```

Comment: check the `feature_importances_` , may be one variable can classify your data correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Can You tell us more what is the target value? For classification Problem you can use LGBM which will hopefully give you better result and try to encode the variable not as LabelEncoder use OneHotEncoder instead.If you have 8 categories LabelEncoder will give more importance to the 8 than 0. One more tuning that you can do is changing the value of max_depth or less and then see the result.
I hope it helps!